# Is it halal to have football players on my phone wallpaper?

Tags: halal-haram

Assalamualaikum wa rahmatullahi brothers and sisters, I use my phone very often and I love football, not just playing it but also watching my favorite players and clubs play. And I thought about putting some of my favorite football players on my wallpaper, but I'm not sure if it is halal or haram to have people on my wallpaper.